# Images not being saved when they are the only field changed

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I filed an issue ticket with symfony on github, but I need a workaround: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5150

I created an entity with an associated image, and I'm saving it using a lifecycle callback as described in the symfony docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html#using-lifecycle-callbacks

When A user filled out the form, and hits save, everything works fine. However, if the only item the user fills/edits is the image, then the form is not saved. I believe this is because symfony doesn't see a change to the entity, so it doesn't bother to repersist the entity, and thus the pre/post persist functions are never called.

I need some way to force the entity to persist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a updated Date field. At the setter of your file line set this updated field to the current date. Now everything should work fine.

Comment: Where should I do that, in the isValid section of my controller?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a field for file uploads in your form and a field for the path.
If you change your setFile method to change the file path entity it should save correctly. For example:

```
public function setFile($file)
{
    if (! empty($file)) {
        $this->photo = 'changed';
    }
    $this->file = $file;
}
```

Comment: I don't have a setfile method like this in my entity - doctrine doesn't make (or use) setters/getters for object properties that aren't persisted.

Comment: It's use it if property not in public scope.

Comment: Don't know about that, but my setup is according to the guide i linked to, and I dont have getters/setters for it.